# How can I recieve color output from console application (like Far)?

Tags: c#, winapi, c#-4.0, console

I have some code:

```
cmdProcess = new Process();
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( "cmd", "/k "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Far Manager\\Far.exe"" );

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += ( s, e ) => {
       callbackFn(e.Data + "\n");
};
cmdProcess.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

cmdProcess.Start();
cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

But with this code I only can launch the process and get something, but not completely and not color. Also I tried the `ReceiveConsoleOutput` function and I receive only blank buffer.
With WinAPI i can only start console and nothing else - I don't understand it well. But I'm not against WinAPI examples, because i think that my problem may be solved with it.
I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

P.S. I'm sorry for bad english.

Comment: I doubt that you can read the colour of the output

Comment: In these projects, it is somehow possible:
[link](https://github.com/cbucher/console)
[link](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu)

Comment: I don't see any evidence that those projects create subprocesses, and then capture the color of each character that is output. Anyway, if I'm wrong, then I guess you can read the code from those projects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Also I saw [Python example](https://github.com/wuub/SublimePTY) that can do it, but code in this one was not too easy to understand. And in that Python example also was used WinAPI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ConEmu and console projects have a lot of code on C++, that I can't understand. If I could understand it, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: I guess it's time to learn. If you can't understand the code you need to write, then you are in effect asking us to do your job for you. That's not what this site is about. Anyway, I still see no evidence that any of the programs you link to are capturing output and re-displaying it. I think that they are hosting the actual process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ReadConsoleOutput code is not working as it should because it is not FreeConsole function was called - for exemption from its own console application

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3yGu.jpg)

```
        public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFromBuffer(IntPtr hOutput, short x, short y, short width, short height)
        {
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(width * height * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHAR_INFO)));
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();

        try
        {
            COORD coord = new COORD();
            SMALL_RECT rc = new SMALL_RECT();
            rc.Left = x;
            rc.Top = y;
            rc.Right = (short)(x + width - 1);
            rc.Bottom = (short)(y + height - 1);

            COORD size = new COORD();
            size.X = width;
            size.Y = height;

            if (!ReadConsoleOutput(hOutput, buffer, size, coord, ref rc))
            {
                // 'Not enough storage is available to process this command' may be raised for buffer size > 64K (see ReadConsoleOutput doc.)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            IntPtr ptr = buffer;
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
                {
                    CHAR_INFO ci = (CHAR_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(CHAR_INFO));
                    char[] chars = Console.OutputEncoding.GetChars(ci.charData);
                    sb.Append(chars[0]);
                    ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHAR_INFO));
                }
                yield return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
    }
```

...

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = command; 
        //proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        bool resultFree = ConsoleApi.FreeConsole();

        if (resultFree)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FreeConsole: {0}", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FreeConsole: {0}", false);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Process ID: {0}", Convert.ToUInt32(proc.Id));

        bool result = ConsoleApi.AttachConsole( Convert.ToUInt32(proc.Id) );

        Debug.WriteLine("AttachConsole: {0}", result);

        IntPtr _consoleH = ConsoleApi.GetStdHandle(ConsoleApi.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        ConsoleApi.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO _bufferInfo;

        bool getInfo = ConsoleApi.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(_consoleH, out _bufferInfo);

        if (getInfo)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo: {0}x{1}", _bufferInfo.dwSize.X, _bufferInfo.dwSize.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo: {0}", false);
        }

        short _widthConsole = _bufferInfo.dwSize.X;
        short _heightConsole = _bufferInfo.dwSize.Y;

        IEnumerable<string> rows = ConsoleApi.ReadFromBuffer(_consoleH, 0, 0, _widthConsole,_heightConsole);

        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(row);
        }
```

Read colors:

```
                    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
                    public static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputAttribute(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
       [Out] ushort[] lpAttribute, uint nLength, COORD dwReadCoord,
       out uint lpNumberOfAttrsRead);
```

...

```
                    string[] colors = new string[]{
                        "black",
                        "darkblue",
                        "darkgreen",
                        "darkcyan",
                        "darkred", 
                        "darkmagenta",
                        "brown",
                        "white",
                        "lightgrey",
                        "blue",
                        "green",
                        "cyan",
                        "red",
                        "magenta",
                        "yellow",
                        "white"
                    };

                for (int i = 0; i < _rowsList.Length; i++)
                {

                    ushort[] lpAttr = new ushort[_widthConsole];

                    ConsoleApi.COORD _coordReadAttr = new ConsoleApi.COORD(0,(short)i);

                    uint lpReadALast;

                    bool readAttr = ConsoleApi.ReadConsoleOutputAttribute(_consoleH, lpAttr, Convert.ToUInt32(_widthConsole), _coordReadAttr, out lpReadALast);

                    string[] attrText = new string[_widthConsole];

                    for (int _attr = 0; _attr < lpAttr.Length; _attr++)
                    {
                        string _text = colors[lpAttr[_attr] & 0x0F];
                        string _background = colors[((lpAttr[_attr] & 0xF0) >> 4) & 0x0F];

                        attrText[_attr] = _text + "|" + _background;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Background color and text can be obtained using this method: ReadConsoleOutputAttribute

Comment: Does this answer the question you asked?

Comment: @David Heffernan yes

Comment: Really. Where do you read the colour of the text output by the external process?

Comment: @David Heffernan I've edited the answer
Output of the original program: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jW7zb.jpg
Output of my program: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KuvTC.jpg

Comment: Ah, you added the missing information in an edit just now

Comment: Could you post the entire code on a Github gist? It would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You talk about two different things. ConEmu and the original console has color support, but this is achieved via the [console buffer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([here](http://mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip) is a complete C# library). The console supports not just coloring but cursors and mouse, too; however, none of them have anything to do with the standard output.

But if you want to receive color information in the standard output, you can use the [ANSI escape sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html), which is a standard in terminal communication (and this is used for [ANSI graphics art](https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi%20graphics&sa=G&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwilj7Lc667LAhUiMJoKHW5_ALMQsAQILg&biw=1920&bih=1129), too), supports coloring and cursor positioning as well and can be encoded as a character stream.

But if the process you call does not dump ANSI sequences, (`cmd` does not do this) you will not receive any color information.

Comment: So, can you explain how to use console buffer API in C#? Or bring me, please, a few links with working tutorials/examples?

Comment: I've edited the answer, a link to C# library has been added.

Comment: This library to create console applications more low-level than is standard in C# but not for data already create a console process, but still thanks for the answer!